# Can SO add an option to delete the answer for the questioner or moderators?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta

I am asking this option because of some useless answers I got for my question.
I can down-vote those but there is no use.

If I can delete that useless answer, my question will be noticed as unanswered question and I may get better answers.

I flagged the answer to be deleted, but nothing happened.

SO has an option to close the question; why don't you add an option to close answers, or make it not considered an answer.

Comment: FWIW, if you have enough reputation you can vote to delete answers with negative votes. If questioners could arbitrarily delete answers.... the horror!

Comment: Just because you as the question asker finds the answers useless doesn't mean they will be found useless to everyone else who stumbles across the question.  But if you truly believe they contribute nothing or contribute negatively and flag them, the moderators will make judgement.

Comment: @Corey: I suspect he's been question-banned.

Comment: @SLaks: Viewing their profile... that makes sense.

Comment: Question bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time to ask your next question. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to ask questions again.

If you tripped the heuristic by just a tiny bit, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure. And even if you're lucky then you're still very close to being banned again, if you get new downvotes.

Comment: How the hell did you get 2000+ rep yet not know about [meta]???

Comment: @wont How the hell you dont know that am banned??

Comment: Another example of why [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) should be implemented.

Answer (score 8):

Moderators and 20K+ users can delete answers.

You can flag an answer for moderator attention and request that it be deleted.

However, we do not delete answers lightly; the answer must be clearly bad for it to be deleted.

Comment: I just want to add (since it is so often mis-used) that an answer being *wrong* is not enough to get it deleted.  It really has to be *not an answer* at all, or actively harmful in some way.

Comment: +1, a broken watch is right twice a day (or all day, given a loose enough specification).

Comment: The answer in question was not very good, but it was clearly an answer. Just downvote and move on.

Answer (score 6):

If the answers on your question are at a score of 0 or below then it will be "unanswered" by the definition used on the site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)

> 324,334
>   questions with **no upvoted answers**

If you leave a comment as well explaining *why* the answer doesn't answer your question then someone (hopefully) the OP will come along and edit it to make it better. If you do leave a comment make it constructive.