# Why isn't it possible to add TABs in the body text field when using the Stack Overflow text editor?

Tags: stack-overflow, discussion

In the Stack Overflow text editor we are not able to add tab characters -- pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will instead switch to the next text field (for entering tags). I checked the CKeditor demo, and it does the same thing. Is it possible for the editor to provide the option to add tab characters within the editor?

Comment: for eg:- i will post a db table structure as a question . for aligning it properly the column in "word" i can TAB. but in SO editor i cant . Why

Comment: soon it will be moved to meta

Comment: Another example of why [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) should be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably designed that way. But it does support tabs in a way.

A standard textarea usually doesn't accept tabs without modifications (ex: Javascript: http://ajaxian.com/archives/handling-tabs-in-textareas).
The SO site doesn't implement that feature.

But you can copy and paste tabs like here:  tab tab tab
But they won't show as HTML treats tabs as whitespaces so basically they will appear as spaces.

```
But here    tab tab taaab   tab will show.
```

Because code is put in pre (preformated) tags that will display tabulations and will use a fixed width font.

So if you want to display preformated text add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line and there you will have access to tabulations.

Comment: But tab will only be four spaces wide (at least that is what I'm seeing) so you probably want to use two of them.

Comment: Yeah... My example didn't work with the word tab followed by an actual tab. But I think the OP is answered none the less an will be happy to tab as much as he likes now... That might have frightening consequences.