# Why am I not able to migrate my question to another StackExchange site?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, discussion

I ask a question in SO.

When I understand SO is not the right place, is there any option that I can

migrate my question to ux stack exchange or webmasters?

Now as I know, I have to wait for 5 people to make it close and migrate.

The guy who ask question / author should be able to migrate the question if he is a member of other websites too.

This question should be on meta. I will wait for 5 guys to close it and migrate!

I wish this can be added as a feature which will be available for users who is not banned from other websites:-)

Comment: Like now: you have to wait until 5 guys close it and migrate to meta ;-)

Comment: Isn't this a _meta_ question ? ;)

Comment: You can always flag for moderator attention - or better still ask on the right site :)

Comment: Another example of why [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) should be implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. If you've not received any answers, you can *delete your question and re-post it on the correct site.*
2. If you've already received answers, flag the post for moderator attention:

> [image: Flag]

Of course, the best solution is to ask it on the right site in the first place.