# Can I manually move question to another community?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I sometimes want to move question to another community manually instead of flagging it. Can I do it and if I can, how many reputation needed for that action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you reach 3000 reputation you can [cast close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) on questions.

One of the close reasons is "Off Topic" and when choosing it, you're given list of some relevant sites that you can choose from.

For example on Stack Overflow you get this dialog:

[image: close as off topic]

When a questions have 5 close votes, it's automatically Closed.

If most close votes (4 or more) are "off topic" and chose the same site, the  question is then automatically migrated to that site. Anything fewer and the question is just closed as "off topic".

If the person who posted the question has no account in the target site, the question author will appear gray there until he log in and associate the accounts.

**Note**: if the question author has account on the target site, and that account is blocked from asking questions (or is under suspension) [**the question can't be migrated, even by a moderator**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination). It will still be closed, but even 100 votes won't migrate it.

Comment: And what if user isn't registered in another community?

Comment: @mesiesta: The question will still be moved.  I believe (but haven't seen for sure) that the user is still properly notified of responses in their Stack Exchange inbox (top left of the page).  That way they can visit the site and register an account if need be.

Comment: @mesiesta: Then the question will have a grayed-out username. If the user registers on that site with the same credentials as the original site, they should automatically regain "ownership" of the question.

Comment: @mesiesta valid point, see my edit.