# Why can't I move flag to Programmers?

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When flagging a question it should be markable that it belongs to programmers.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135235/when-flagging-a-question-it-should-be-markable-that-it-belongs-to-programmers-se)

I recently flagged a post ([the decisive difference between LGPL and AGPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996160/the-decisive-difference-between-lgpl-and-agpl)) that should have been moved to Programmers but this was not available at the flag move dialog.

In the screenshot of this answer ([Can I manually move question to another community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119469/165123)) it was still available.

Also I would like to know if there was the possibility to give the author of the question the right to move the question (maybe only once) on his/her own to another SE site where he/she has an account. Of course this should not be possible if the question was already moved by a moderator (to prevent the author from moving it back).

Comment: For the first part, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134830/what-happened-to-off-topic-belongs-on-programmers

Comment: Please never again post migration comments.

Answer (score 2):

Authors with 15 points or more can already flag their own posts for moderator attention; they could use that to request a migration.

I doubt that there are many posts being made where the author wanted to subsequently move the post elsewhere; in most cases the SO community is quite happy to help flag off-topic questions and questions get migrated rapidly.

I don't think authors should be able to migrate their questions without review, however. Even with peer-migrated questions (to pre-configured targets) we see plenty of questions being rejected on the target site, if migrations are possible by *just* the author I very much fear  that the migration statistics are going to get worse for it. If the author wasn't able to figure out on their own where to post the question in the first place, I fully expect that most authors also won't bother to check the target site FAQ before migrating.

Comment: The idea was to move the work from the moderators. So the flagging solution defeats this idea.