# Cannot migrate question to SO because asker is not allowed to ask questions there

Tags: support, migration, moderation, post-ban

If a user is on one SE site, and they ask a question that is off-topic for that site, but is on-topic for another site, the obvious solution is to migrate it to the appropriate site.

I'm currently dealing with a situation where the question (a generic python question) should be migrated to Stack Overflow, but the asker is blocked from asking questions on Stack Overflow (which could explain why the question was posted on SQA).

What is the appropriate action? Attempting to migrate it results in it being closed as off-topic, but not migrated because of the asker's inability to ask on SO.

Comment: Would it be a good SO question?  Chances are it shouldn't be migrated, but deleted.

Comment: User is question-blocked. User avoids such by posting elsewhere hoping for migration. Migration is disallowed. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: The OP is referring to [this post](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/how-do-i-sum-two-values-in-a-dictionary-using-python) (I assume), which is a pretty terrible question.

Comment: This is by design: [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just delete it. Going to other sites to ask off-topic questions in order to avoid a ban is not something we should encourage by allowing the question to be migrated back to wherever. You don't see us migrating all the off-topic questions that get asked here on Meta (not that *all* of them are due to question bans), do you? Before deletion, you could leave a comment explaining that this is bad behavior to discourage it from happening again.

Comment: Will the question being closed versus the question being deleted have any impact on the user being auto-banned from SQA? That is to say, will it happen faster if the questions are deleted?

Comment: They do affect it. I don't know what algorithms they use to determine question bans, but I would assume that a deletion would have a greater impact than just a closure (especially for cases where the closure was a duplicate question). Of course, downvotes on the question would also increase the impact.

Comment: @corsiKa The algorithm is super secret (not even us diamonds know it), but deleted questions & answers definitely count. However the question ban is _not_ on by default on most sites, and it's probably off on SQA, you'll need to talk to a Stack Exchange employee if you want them to switch it on.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase my question - is there a real compelling reason to delete as opposed to leaving it closed?

Comment: Well, generally you don't want to leave random crap-off-topic questions laying around the site closed. If there's no reason to keep it, then delete it. :)

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, the reason being that it's horribly off topic for your site. Why keep it? What's the point of having a generic python question visible on SQA? And if the behaviour persists, I'd suspend, being a repeated violation of the rules. If what you are asking is "will deleting the closed question will contribute _more_ towards a question ban than keeping it around closed", that I don't know and I don't think Stack Exchange will ever tell us.