# Is it ok to use an alternate account while my main user is restricted?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I'm new to Stack Exchange, and my main user only has 16+ rep. And it's been blocked in Code Review. I need to use Code Review today. Should I use an alternate account?

Comment: Here we have reputation points - karma comes when users try to use more than one account.

Comment: *Dear officer, my driving license has been suspended. Is it OK if I use one assigned to a fake identity of mine?*

Comment: see also [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/165773) and [Why have I been barred from posting questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773)

Answer (score 15):

No, you should not. Your main account has been blocked for a reason. You should take appropriate action to reverse the block.

Answer (score 4):

Judge yourself: do moderators block you so as you would have to create a new account? It does make no sense. The block is supposed to be an "emergency break" ([don't speed ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide)). You should at least look around you and try to find the reason for it.

If there were some problems with your posts, you might want to post more carefully now, trying to provide less content of not really good quality, and not immediately removing downvoted posts (but fixing them!), because this will contribute to another ban pretty fast.

But trying to create another account is dishonest (and illegal - you won't succeed with using Code Review by spawning new accounts anyway - this will be detected). Yes, you need to use Code Review today, but you probably didn't follow the rules while using it before? Then it's time to do that, though - with your *existing* account.

Comment: "break", or "brake"? I guess there's some wordplay here!

Comment: @Nathan :Pun everywhere!

Answer (score -9):

No. It is not ethical. There is a reason why accounts are banned or restricted. They may hinder you early on but you should learn from them and work to fixing whatever discrepancy got you restricted or banned. Maybe get an account from a friend or family member?

Comment: Using an account from a  friend or family member is against the [ToS](http://stackexchange.com/legal) *The Services are accessed by You (“Subscriber” or “You”) under the following terms and conditions*

Comment: Lol? Not ethical to use banned account, but ethical to use an account of another person to bypass the ban?..