# How can I ask a question again?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

About 2 years ago, I wrote some VERY bad questions which obviously got down voted and one question just got closed off because it was irrelevant or because the question was not clear.

Recently, I wanted to have the privilege to be able to ask questions again. I decided to contribute positively to the community by answering questions where I can and I have been a bit successful. I managed to double my reputation points.

Now what I don't understand is, I want to be able to improve the questions I asked two years back but those questions are relevant to me anymore nor do I remember the problems not I have the code. I just don't know what to do about this. I know I cannot delete them, because it will make it worse.

Can someone please, tell me what I can do about these questions?

I hope I don't downvoted and I am aware there are probably duplicate questions. I just want some help.

MY question is unique because it mentions I am trying to improve my existing posts but they are irrelevant and I dont remember the problems nor do I ahve the code anymore.

Thanks,

Comment: I told you I am writing to fix my exisiting posts. I mentioned that @gnat

Comment: on a related note, did you consider deleting account and restarting at a rate of one question a week [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773)? (duplicate target also mentions this but only as one of many other options)

Comment: That answer is for someone have LIMIITED questions @gnat

Comment: per my reading it is about banned users: "you had an account that was *blocked from asking questions*, and returned after requesting deletion of your account, which we obliged..."

Comment: I did not request to get my account deleted at all @gnat

Comment: I contacted stack overflow and they just referred to that post again!! @gnat

Comment: OMG! I can ask questions again!!!!  @gnat

Comment: Yay! You don't see most of them end like this.

Comment: hahah thanks @Rubisco

Answer (score 6):

I can ask questions again.

Well, surprisingly editing my old questions did help. For future reference, I made sure I improved the body of the question and gave it a proper title. I think its the minor things that help

Also answered so many questions with as much as detail as I can.

I still have a limit. I am going to make sure, I ask questions with much detail as I can.