# If a mod tries to migrate a question of mine to another site in which I'm blocked - probably without me knowing it, is it problematic for me?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, migration, time, migration-block

It is unclear to me if a mod's try to migrate a question of mine to another site in which I'm blocked (which obviously cannot happen), is problematic for me in the sense, for example, that it can lengthen the duration of a block of asking questions in that particular website to which that mod tried to migrate my question → in some extent.

If a mod tries to migrate a question of mine to another site in which I'm blocked - probably without me knowing it, is it problematic for me?

Comment: @Rob TL DR ; there are many answers there and I wouldn't associate the questions as I deal with "it was already done".

Comment: Rob, I have asked to delete the question and flagged it with a long explanation why based on JG's answer-comments.

Comment: Well, besides leaving it to the mods' consideration I think the rest would be a waste of time ; kindly,

Comment: It is useful to improve downvoted Q&As: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/282094

Comment: How is this a duplicate? None of the questions linked answer this one. This question is asking whether or not a question ban will be affected if a mod tries to migrate a question to a site where the asker is banned. This isn't covered by any of the dupe targets, the closest just mentions that such migrations will fail, but don't explain that it will not affect the ban in any way.

Comment: @terdon both answers state that nothing will happen because the migration simply isn't possible. The target site won't even know about it. Only those mods being asked to do the migration on the source site might take issue.

Comment: @RobertLongson nothing would happen to the site, yet, but I feel as the account might be effected by the block becoming longer --- I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnDoea I'm not sure how much more clearly we can state that nothing happens on the target site.

Comment: @RobertLongson stating is fine, but without evidence, after what I felt in the past that a block became longer, I doubt that and considering there might be some mistake here ; maybe I have the mistake and the 6 months ban was just intact and I was wrong to think it became longer ; in this opportunity I will share with you that IMO these 6 months bans are a disgrace and a stain on the community.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It'll fail, and the mod trying to migrate will get grumpy.

If it looks like an obvious attempt to get around a question ban, you would have to deal with whatever the mods on the site you posted on decide to.

At best it'll get closed. At worst, you get a mod message or a suspension.

If its a single honest mistake, meh. No big deal

In most cases the conjunction of a question banned user, off topic question worth migrating and a mod trying to do it is pretty rare.

In any case, if this happens, if you post a question and a mod tries to migrate it to a site where you are question banned, nothing will happen. The migration will be rejected and your ban on the target site won't be affected in any way.

Comment: Hello JG ; Dammnit these down votes. Can or should this question be deleted?

Comment: This question **is** the most helpful --- perhaps it's needed for deletion.

Comment: After all I asked the question after 7 years of experience here ; I assume new users won't ask it.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are less about usefulness and more about the possibility of abuse

Comment: Well, one can believe me or not if I say I didn't ask it about abuse, but if people don't believe me about it - I personally prefer the question to be deleted, if it's allowed by mods.

Comment: What possibility of abuse? This seems to be asking about the case where a mod decides to migrate and it turns out the asker is question banned on the target site. This isn't something that can be abused, and JohnDoea is wondering whether such a migration can affect the block on the target. The answer is no, because the migration will fail, but I don't see any possibilities for abuse.

Comment: Pretty much. Not quite angry, but a little annoyed

Answer (score 7):

Even moderators [can't migrate questions to sites where you're question banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination). Otherwise it would just be a loophole people would exploit to get round the ban. You need to [get out of the ban first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

If ask for impossible migrations repeatedly knowing you are banned the source site mods will be less than impressed and likely do something to stop you. If not and this is a single honest mistake I'm sure you'll be fine.

As far as the target site is concerned, its mods won't even know anything happened. Your situation there will be exactly as it was before you asked for the migration.